# Steps to deploy angular 8 along with asp.net core 3.1

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have currently created a stand alone Angular 8 Application which is not .net core. I used to deploy it in the IIS and another .net core 3.1 Web Application for WEB API, which is hosted separately and the UI calls the API URL.

Now I have to deploy both together, so I have to merge my Angular 8 application into .net core

Is there a way I could do that instead of going from creating a new .net Core Web Application of type Angular? Is there any best practices for deploying both API and angular application together?

Comment: to do this. you need to create www root in core api and from startup u need to enable www folder to reach. then put your angular dist folder inside this folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My steps to deploy an ASP.NET Core Web API 2.2 and Angular 8 application to a hosting provider. Maybe it would be helpful for you.

1. Create a folder `wwwroot` into `ASP.NET Core Web API` project if there is no `wwwroot` folder
2. Run `ng build --prod` in your Angular application.
3. Copy these build files from the above step into `wwwroot` folder. You can find your created bundle by seeing `"outputPath": "dist/YourAppl",` in `angular.json` file
4. Publish your ASP.NET Core Web API into folder. Right click at project -> Publish

Put published folder into folder of your website.

This is a `web.config` in case you want to see detailed errors of your deployed application. It is really helpful to know what should be edited into your deployed application as thrown exceptions can be seen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" 
                resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\fooAppl.dll" 
            stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
            hostingModel="InProcess" >
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" 
                    value="Development" />
            </environmentVariables>     
         </aspNetCore>
      </system.webServer>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

[In addition, you can read a great article about deploying ASP.NET Core Web API to IIS](https://medium.com/@aram161287/deploy-asp-net-core-web-api-on-iis-f75e755a6402)

Answer (score 4):

1) create wwwroot in api project if not exists

2) in startup allow  `app.UseDefaultFiles(); app.UseStaticFiles();`

3) prod your angular `ng  build --prod`

4) put you angular dist inside to this wwwroot folder