# Is it wise to deploy an Angular application in a host while the API which serves that application is in another host?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I want to host my Angular application in a free hosting service. My app needs to connect to an ASP.NET Core API. Do I need to use another ASP.NET hosting to host my API and link the Angular app to that API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it depends on the scenario you got. If you can choose between those alternatives, pick to deploy it in the same host.

Mobile apps run that way. Application runs in user's device and api runs in the server. Works almost the same way.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can host your backend inside the same hosting service.
Here is a link for the first steps [Steps to deploy angular 8 along with asp.net core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62235867/steps-to-deploy-angular-8-along-with-asp-net-core-3-1) to get you started.
Good luck